# What is the best practice to cache images on Android?

Tags: android, database, image, caching

In my application I use SoftReference to cache images, it is working fine with active internet connection. And now I need to cache images, so I could use it in offline mode.

What is the best way to implement it? 
Use complex solution with SoftReference and database? or maybe SoftReference and local storage (sdcard)?

I would appreciate your advices. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

2 level cache in memory and on disk. Check out the  https://github.com/mttkay/droid-fu project on github. It contains an ImageCache that works this way.

Comment: I tried WebImageView (from droid-fu) library but I cannot get it working, image is not loading. I have created Application extended from DroidFuApplication and configured it it manifest, even I've extended main activity from BetterDefaultActivity. But I still see only loading animation.

Do you have working example?

My code onCreate() of the Main activity is following:

        WebImageView img = (WebImageView) findViewById(R.id.webimage);
        img.setImageUrl("http://static.technorati.com/09/12/13/2291/android.jpg");
        img.loadImage();

What is wrong with it?

Comment: that should work. Are there any exceptions in logcat? Does your app have the INTERNET permission?

Comment: Yes, internetn permission is here, also I added permission to write to local storage.

Comment: In Log I see following:
06-09 22:58:30.594: WARN/LocaleService(22485): onCreate
06-09 22:58:30.684: WARN/LocaleService(22485): onStart
06-09 22:58:30.964: WARN/ImageLoader(22447): download for http://static.technorati.com/09/12/13/2291/android.jpg failed (attempt 1)
06-09 22:58:33.794: WARN/ImageLoader(22447): download for http://static.technorati.com/09/12/13/2291/android.jpg failed (attempt 2)
06-09 22:58:36.704: WARN/ImageLoader(22447): download for http://static.technorati.com/09/12/13/2291/android.jpg failed (attempt 3)

Comment: Why download is failed? May I ask you, do you have working example?

Comment: Finally, I've got it working. I suspect there was problem with my internet connection.
I have tried to implement ListView with WebImageView as item renderer and I found strange behavior. First time all images are loading into first list item, but after that when images are loading from cache it is working fine.
Have you experienced such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, But I hope it still counts for something. ImageDownloader is the best one for the job. I also found a slight variation of the class at:

http://theandroidcoder.com/utilities/android-image-download-and-caching/

The main difference between the two is that the ImageDownloader uses the Android caching system, and the modified one uses internal and external storage as caching, keeping the cached images indefinitely or until the user removes it manually. The author also mentions Android 2.1 compatibility.

Regards, EZFrag